# Android CORS requests work only once?

Tags: android, webkit, xmlhttprequest, cors

When testing CORS requests under the Android emulator, I stumbled upon a strange error. Try for example following website: http://arunranga.com/examples/access-control/

When using a CORS request for the first time, everything seems to work fine. But the second time it doesn't work anymore!

I tried following alternatives:

- Android 2.1, 2.2, 3.0 emulators => fail
- Android device (Samsung Apollo 5801) => fail
- Other CORS sites (including home made CORS supported site) => fail

After restarting the browser, it works again... but again, only the first time.

I guess the problem is somewhere in the Android Webkit code. I have some experience programming Android but can not seem to find this exact problem.

Anyone met this problem and found a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this just now.
The Android browser has some strange caching issues you need to be aware of, so try the workarounds in [link removed][1].

Comment: I got it more or less working using following line on the server side: header("Cache-Control: no-cache");

Another problem popped up with credentials being sent... but I will create a new topic for his.